# Is possible to access the clipboard Linux Mint through Photoshop?

Tags: linux-mint, clipboard, wine, photoshop-cs6

I have Linux Mint 17 installed and am using Photoshop CS6 through Wine but the clipboard does not work, if I try to copy an image in the browser and then paste in Photoshop directly does not work, I do not want to save the image and then open in Photoshop, it spends much more time.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can often use the Cut or Copy command to copy selections between Photoshop Elements and other applications. The cut or copied selection remains on the Clipboard until you cut or copy another selection.

In some cases, the contents of the Clipboard can be converted to a raster image. Photoshop Elements prompts you to paste the vector artwork as pixels or as a shape layer.

Note: The image is rasterized at the resolution of the file into which you paste it.
```

refer the below link for more details;

http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/tutorials/PhotoshopEl/Help/help.html

Comment: If I copy an image from the browser and then try to create a new document with the copied image, photoshop does not recognize the previously copied image.